# A better way to write null reference with return value in c#

Tags: c#, null-check

Is there a better way to write this null check? I'm checking a table from a `DataSet` for nulls.

```
if (dataSet == null || dataSet.Tables == null || dataSet.Tables[0].Rows == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error at {nameof(dataSet)}");
    return vatPeriodList;
}
```

I'm working in ADO.NET.

Comment: [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) `dataSet?.Tables?[0]?.Rows == null`

Comment: `if (dataSet?.Tables?[0]?.Rows == null)`

Comment: Ada looks like C# now?

Comment: define "better"? Are there actually circumstances in which you realistically expect `dataSet` itself to be null? Or even the Tables?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I'm guessing ADO.Net ;)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError no, just 3-4 years of changes. You haven't seen `var value = dataSet?.Tables?[0]?.Rows ?? throw new ArgumentNullException()` yet

Comment: @fubo not quite a duplicate. What if `Rows` is empty?

Comment: Your check doesn't make sense and also forgets one important. A DataRow in a table **never** can be `null`, so the last check is redundant. `DataSet.Tables` also can't be `null`, so the second is also redundant. But you forgot that the DataSet could not contain any tables.  In that case your `if` throws an exception at `dataSet.Tables[0]`. You could use: `if (dataSet?.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Any() == false){//..}`

Comment: @fubo Thanks, that was what I was looking for =)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've reopened the question - feel free to write your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if(dataSet?.Tables?.FirstOrDefault()?.Rows == null) {}
```

`FirstOrDefault()` returns the first entry or null if there is none.

Comment: You should probably explain why you used `FirstOfDefault()` instead of `?[0]`

Comment: `Tables` is a `DataTableCollection` which can't be accessed with linq without casting - this shouldn't compile

Comment: Even if this would compile it doesn't make sense to check if the `DataRowCollection` returned by the [`DataTable.Rows`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,0a1e7beda181de9e)-property is `null`. This is never the case because it's a read-only property and the (default) constructor initializes it.

Comment: If the result of `dataSet?.Tables.FirstOrDefault()?` is null then the whole term is null as well.

Comment: But if the Dataset isn't null and contains at least one table it doesn't make sense to check the Rows property

Answer (score 4):

Your check doesn't make sense and also forgets one important.

- `DataSet.Tables` also can't be `null` because it's a readonly property, you can't assign `null`, so the second check is pointless.
- `dataSet.Tables[0].Rows` can't be `null` because it's a readonly property, you can't assign `null`, so the last check is redundant.

But you forgot that the `DataSet` could be empty, so doesn't contain any `DataTables`.  In that case your `if` throws an exception at `dataSet.Tables[0]`.

I would use:

```
int? firstTablesRowCount = dataSet?.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().FirstOrDefault()?.Rows.Count;
if (firstTablesRowCount.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error at {nameof(dataSet)}");
}
```

This ensures that the `DataSet` isn't null and contains tables and that the first table contains rows.